# Use of Grade Levels Instead of Age

Tags: american-english, time, transatlantic-differences

Why do Americans use grade levels to indicate the passage of time instead of actual age? (i.e. “When I was in 12th grade” vs. “When I was 17, 18, etc.)

Comment: Because it's how kids in the US remember things.

Comment: @HotLicks so a couple of years down the line, they'll stop using school terminology?

Comment: Not just the USA.  Here in Brazil my son (13) is in Year 8 at school.  Kids start school at five years of age. First grade is the first year of school, second grade is the second year, and so on.  Seems very straightforward.  All you need to do is subtract five from the child's age to get the grade, or add five to grade to get the age. Also, unlike the UK, kids can be held back or made to repeat a grade if they don't pass so, kids much older than 9 can still be stuck in 4th grade

Comment: @WeatherVane - Then it's "When I was a freshman in college" or "When I first started working at XYZ".  What's so surprising??

Comment: I've always assumed AmE ***in Year N*** just meant ***in the Nth year of full-time education*** (starting from around age 4 or 5). Except for the (rare?) possibility of being "held back" and made to repeat a year.

Comment: @HotLicks no surprise. In UK I think they now use "year 11" and so on, but when I was at school, the classes were named differently, such as "Lower Sixth" and "Upper Sixth".

Comment: If I'm ever asked how hold I was when something happened to me in high school, I have to remember what grade I was in—and then add 5 years to that in order to come up with my age at the time. I *never* think of my age when i think of my time in high school; I have to translate.

Comment: Because, contextually, the grade seems more important than the age to the speaker.  When age is more important, an AmE speaker will use age not grade.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but I don't think this is a matter of language so much as culture and context. Sometimes when marking a location I will use coordinates, sometimes step-by-step directions, and sometimes landmarks. In the same way, sometimes I relate a story from when I was 7 years 10 months old, sometimes from whenI had just earned my green belt in youth taekwondo, and sometimes from the third grade.

Comment: Memory often works with events, e.g., I learned to canoe at summer camp.

Comment: The same way we use minutes to measure distance. Question: "How far is it to Dallas from Houston?" Answer: "About 4 hours, longer if you stop at Buc-ee's."

Comment: As a native English speaker, this makes zero sense to me.

Comment: This isn't just an American thing, we do it in Australia too. (Not in all circumstances, but it's common.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn’t about English; it is about local customs.

Comment: The same thing is done in France, and in other European countries as well. The practice is definitely not specific to the United States.

Answer (score 17):

As an American, I can say that public schooling in the U.S. represents for us a kind of social coming-of-age system (especially during the high school years, which usually encompass the ages of 14-18), and as such is emotionally significant in some odd way.

Additionally, grade levels group us in ways that ages sometimes do not. Due to "cutoff age" rules, one grade—10th grade, for example—will typically have students who start the school year at age 14 or 15 and end it at ages 15 and 16, respectively, depending on their birth dates. Therefore, "when I was in 10th grade" is a time period relatable due to its sociological circumstance rather than a particular age. (BTW, I have no documentation to back this up; I am just musing based on my own experiences.)

Comment: Yes, a big part of "grades" is the social connections, and the fact that everyone in the "grade" is pretty much going through the same "growing up experiences" together.

Comment: So "Nth Grade" isn't so much about when you started to learn biology, but when you started dating?

Comment: I guess so, @WeatherVane, but where I come from, learning biology and dating are almost the same thing.

Comment: That's why I chose those examples! At my school, the "human biology" class was a thinly disguised lesson in... but it is more up front these days.

Comment: @WeatherVane It can be either, honestly. When making fun of someone for forgetting how to do algebra, for example, you might say "come on, I learned that in the sixth grade".

Answer (score 4):

Not everyone is the same age in the same grade.
Grades are more meaningful as it indicates what things you were studying and your social interactions at that age.

Comment: Though this varies quite a bit from system to system. Some systems feel it's important to keep age groups together, while others are keen on skills and rapid advancement.